# How to convert from System.Windows.Forms.Keys to Char regarding to Current Keyboard Layout?

Tags: .net, user-controls, keyboard, char, overriding

I used below code to get `Character` from `System.Windows.Forms.Keys`.

```vb
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Function MapVirtualKey(uCode As UInteger, uMapType As UInteger) As UInteger
End Function
<Extension> _
Public Function GetVirtualKeyAsChar(ByRef keyData As Keys) As Char
    ' 2 is used to translate into an unshifted character value 
    Return Convert.ToChar(MapVirtualKey(CUInt(keyData), 2))
End Function
```

But it not returns correct characters according to keyboard layout or shift/control states. For example all returned characters are UPPERCASE. And if I use some other input language in textbox it still returns default A-Z letters.

I **need** this to override some pressed keys behaviour **in PreProcessMessage() function**. I know I can use to override OnKeyPress() function to achieve correct results but I really need my process to be done at PreProcessMessage() function:

```vb
Public Overrides Function PreProcessMessage(ByRef m As Message) As Boolean
    Select Case m.Msg
        Case WM_KEYDOWN, WM_SYSKEYDOWN
            ' Extracting keys data that similar to ProcessCmdKey's keyData parameter.
            Dim keyData As Keys = DirectCast(CInt(m.WParam), Keys)
            Select Case keyData
                Case Keys.Back
                    ...
                Case Else
                    Dim ch As Char = GetChar(keyData)
                    ...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16221481/17034

Comment: @HansPassant After checking documentation of `ToUnicodeEx()`  I entirely agree with you to send those bunch of process to `UserControl` itself. Thanks for your great descriptions.